# Can't connect to Solana devnet/testnet

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli

I've been trying to connect to solana devnet/testnet through cli and python solana SDK, but both without success, getting below error from CLI:

"Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (https://api.devnet.solana.com/): operation timed out"

and from python SDK:

"requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.devnet.solana.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f492ffa4490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))"

I CAN connect to localhost using the same method with CLI. Strangely, I can't even find similar issues by googling, so I had to ask here by myself.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Either the public nodes were down for maintenance, or there's a connection issue on your side.  You can do a quick check for network aliveness by running `solana airdrop 1` and `solana balance`.  Otherwise, you can check the status of the different networks at https://status.solana.com/

Comment: Thank you. Most likely the problem is on my network. Just curious why using VPNs still doesn't work.

Comment: @SaiMa How did you solve the problem?

Comment: It turned out to be a network problem in the country I reside. Normal VPNs don't work out. I had to log onto a remote server overseas to connect.